# how to load module from memory, byte code or clean up after load

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, pyd

I have a module in form of byte code - b'fasfasfa', how can I exec() that as when I try I get error  `ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`

Alternatively, how can I import pyd file & delete the file afterwards with module being loaded. I don't want the pyd to be visible to user.

TIA